# kafka stream windowed count output unreadable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying windowed count with word count example. It works fine except that output is partially unreadable.

Code:

```
    StringSerializer stringSerializer = new StringSerializer();
    StringDeserializer stringDeserializer = new StringDeserializer();
    WindowedSerializer<String> windowedSerializer = new WindowedSerializer<>(stringSerializer);
    WindowedDeserializer<String> windowedDeserializer = new WindowedDeserializer<>(stringDeserializer);
    Serde<Windowed<String>> windowedSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(windowedSerializer, windowedDeserializer);

    TimeWindows window = TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)).advanceBy(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1));

    KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input");
    KTable<Windowed<String>, Long> wordCounts = textLines
        .flatMapValues(textLine -> Arrays.asList(textLine.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")))
        .groupBy((key, word) -> word)
        .windowedBy(window)
        .count(Materialized.<String, Long, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("counts-store"));
    wordCounts.toStream().to("streams-plaintext-output", Produced.with(windowedSerde, Serdes.Long()));

    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), config);
    streams.start();
```

Output:

```
kafka c[??   1
yaya c[??    1
kafka c[??   2
```

I guess the unreadable part might be windows duration.
What can I do to let it readable?

**EDIT:**

Tried to use windowedSerde to print output:

```
    KStream<Windowed<String>, Long> output = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-output");
    output.print(windowedSerde, Serdes.Long());
```

It still doesn't work.

Comment: In the original code, there is no `print()` statement? Did you try to read using `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh` ? For the EDIT part, you need to specify the `windowedSerde` in the `builder.stream()` operator.

Comment: Yes, previously I read topic using `kafka-conole-consumer`. If I modify to `KStream<Windowed<String>, Long> output = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-output", Consumed.with(
          windowedSerde, Serdes.Long()));`, it will show `Deserialization exception handler is set to fail upon a deserialization error`.

Comment: You need to specify the `windowedSerde` in `builder.stream(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

When reading from the topic you need to use a Deserializer appropriate for Serializer that was used to produce to the topic. In this case, you need to use the windowDeserializer, which you are already constructing like so:

```
WindowedDeserializer<String> windowedDeserializer = new WindowedDeserializer<>(stringDeserializer);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to use windowedSerde to read topic but still had no luck. Code attached to this post.